# Multiple conditions in if statement on both sides of the logical operator

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logical-operators, multiple-conditions

I was experimenting with having multiple arguments in an if statement on both sides of the logical operator. I first started with the || operator, which worked as expected:

```
var a = 'apple', b = 'banana', c = 'cherry';

if (a == 'banana' || a == 'apple' || b == 'banana' || b == 'apple') {
    console.log('example 1') // returns
}

if ((a || b) == 'banana' || (a || b) == 'apple') {
    console.log('example 2') // returns
}

if (a == ('apple' || 'banana') || b == ('apple' || 'banana')) {
    console.log('example 3') // returns
}

if ((a || b) == ('apple' || 'banana')) {
    console.log('example 4') // returns
}
```

So far, no unexpected results.
However, when following a similar structure when replacing the || operator for the && operator, things don't quite work as I expect them to.

```
if ((a == 'banana' && b == 'apple') || (a == 'apple' && b == 'banana')) {
    console.log('example 5') // returns
}

if (((a || b) == 'banana') && ((a || b) == 'apple')) {
    console.log('example 6') // DOESN'T RETURN
}

if ((a || b) == 'banana') {
    console.log('example 6a') // DOESN'T RETURN - consistent with example 6
}

if ((a == ('apple' || 'banana')) && (b == ('apple' || 'banana'))) {
    console.log('example 7') // DOESN'T RETURN
}

if (a == ('apple' || 'banana')) {
    console.log('example 7a') // returns - inconsistent with example 7
}

if (b == ('apple' || 'banana')) {
    console.log('example 7b') // DOESN'T RETURN - inconsistent with example 7a
}

if ((a && b) == ('apple' || 'banana')) {
    console.log('example 8') // DOESN'T RETURN
}

if ('apple' == (a || b) && 'banana' == (a || b)) {
    console.log('example 9') // DOESN'T RETURN
}
```

Now, I am wondering: is there a flaw in my logic or can it just not be done this way? My aim is to write these if statements as short as possible, for the purpose of readibility and maintainability. Clearly I am just exploring possibilities.

Does anyone know any way to go about this? Especially example 7/7a/7b seems peculiar to me because it yields inconsistent results despite a similar structure [[Fiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/7yy8J/)

Comment: Nope, it can't be done that way, `(a||b) == something` is not valid javascript and fails.

Comment: (a || b) == 'banana' should be (a == 'banana' || b == 'banana')

Comment: As a sidenote, you can do `if ( /(banana|apple)/.test(a) )`

Comment: I haven't ever heard of the .test() method before! @adeneo

Comment: What you have there is quite short and readable. You don't need to make it shorter IMO.

Comment: @AKG - It's for testing regular expressions, and comes in handy sometimes. Here it is on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Logical OR` operator doesn't work in a way you're looking for.

> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either operand is true; if both are false, returns false.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

One alternative way could be make use of array's `indexOf` method. Just be aware it will return the `index` of the array element, so `0` could be a valid value also. In order to make our `if` statement works as expected, we have to use `0 <= ...` like this:

```
if ( 0 <= ["apple","banana"].indexOf(a) ) { ... }
```

The other thing you can do is using `in` operator. Also as it checks only against the `keys`, you can leave the `values` empty like this:

```
if ( a in { "apple": "", "banana": "" } ) { ... }
```

If you have lot's of options, obviously it's better to do the following:

```
var options = {
    "apple": "",
    "banana": ""
}

if ( a in options ) { ... }
```

Personally I think with just two options to check, this will be more readable for a human-eye to go for two separated checks, and I think in your examples you don't really need to shorten the `if` statements as they're already quite short and readable in my opinion.

```
if ( "apple" === a || "banana" === a ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a clean way to check if a variable equals any of a number of other variables, try using a function like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/aYRmL/

```
function equalsAny (first) {
    return !![].slice.call(arguments, 1).filter(function (val) {
        return first === val;
    }).length;
}
```

The first argument is the one being compared to the rest. Use it like this:

```
var a = 'banana', b = 'orange';
equalsAny(a, 'banana', 'apple'); // returns true
equalsAny('orange', a, b); // returns true
```

The first one above accomplishes what you were trying to do with `a == ('banana' || 'apple')`. The seconds accomplishes what you were trying to do with `(a || b) == 'banana'`.

Comment: You could reduce a bit if you pass the first argument as an actual argument, then you slice 1 element of the array and chain the filter. ie http://jsfiddle.net/aYRmL/2/

Comment: @elclanrs yeah this was just a quickie off the top of my head. fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`(a || b) == 'banana'` always will be false because `(a || b)` will return a Boolean witch is not equal to a string</strike>

UPDATE :
 did some testing `(a || b)` always returns the first operand (`a` in this case) witch is 'apple' and not equal to 'banana'.

|| and && will give excepted result only if the both operands are Boolean or can be cased to Boolean.

Comment: JavaScript's `||` doesn't always result in a boolean. It will return the value of `a` or `b` as is. `console.log(1 || 2);` logs `1`, not `true`.

Comment: Because [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 0):

The way it's working is that `a && b` and `a || b` are always set to the value of one of the variables. `a && b` will always be set to the value of `b` unless `a` is `false`, in which case the answer must be `false`. Similarly `a || b` will be set to the value of `a`, unless `a` is `false`, in which case it will be set to the value of `b`. As elclanrs mentioned, this is because of short-circuit evaluation -- the first operand may determine the result, in which case there's no point in looking at the second operand.

When both `a` and `b` are strings, they will never be false unless the string is zero-length. So `a || b` will be 'apple' in your case, and `a && b` will be 'banana'.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution you can use `some` or `every`:

```
var __slice = [].slice;

function any(a) {
  return __slice.call(arguments,1).some(function(x) {
    return a === x;
  });
}

function all(a) {
  return __slice.call(arguments,1).every(function(x) {
    return a === x;
  });
}
```

And use like:

```
// Instead of:
// if (a == 'banana' || a == 'apple' || a == 'orange')
if (any(a, 'banana', 'apple', 'orange')) {
  ...
}

// Instead of:
// if (a == 'banana' && b == 'banana' && c == 'banana')
if (all('banana', a, b, c)) {
  ...
}
```