# else if statement getting ignored

Tags: javascript

I have a function that has to act different if `pan.cost > 0`.

So let's say `curPos = 3` and `pan.cost = -1`

Now when I do this, no matter what, `if(curPos + 1 === 5 || 30)` is always used even if `curPos + 1` is 2,3,4,6 etc (as long `pan.cost < 0`)

Now I have put `console.log(curPos + 1)` inside the `else if-statement` and it also says their that it does not meet the requirements.

```
function action(curPos)
{
  var pan = panel[curPos];

  if(pan.cost > 0)
  {

  }
  else if(curPos + 1 === 5 || 39)
  {
    console.log(curPos + 1);

  }
  else if(curPos + 1 === 3)
  {
    console.log("should be here");

  }
}
```

Comment: Problem area is `if(curPos + 1 === 5 || 39)`, You need `if((curPos + 1) === 5 || (curPos + 1) === 39)`

Comment: No one else thinks it's odd he's setting `pan` to what appears to be a number and then the next line he's treating it like an object?

Comment: @Waxi yes sorry, the object is declared somewhere else. But I thought that wouldn't be relevent for this question

Comment: @Waxi, We have no idea what `panel[curPos]` evaluates to. I'm not sure why you'd think it would be a number.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yeah you're right, not sure why I thought that either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple conditions in if statement on both sides of the logical operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125750/multiple-conditions-in-if-statement-on-both-sides-of-the-logical-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function action(curPos)
{
  var pan = panel[curPos];
  var newCurPos = (curPost + 1);

  if(pan.cost > 0)
  {

  }
  else if(newCurPos === 5 || newCurPos === 39)
  {
    console.log(newCurPos);

  }
  else if(newCurPos === 3)
  {
    console.log("should be here");

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will accept you answer (in 5 minutes), cause you were first. But all other answers were great too!

Comment: Awesome. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

The line

`curPos + 1 === 5 || 39`

always evaluates to truthy, because it is read:

`(curPos + 1 === 5) || 39`

and `39` is a truthy value.

Answer (score 1):

`if(curPos + 1 === 5 || 39)` will always evaluate to true. Look at the part after your or pipes. `if(39)` will always be true.

Answer (score 1):

`|| 39` will always return true and `pan.cost` doesn't exist.