# Different outputs using switch and if else statements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am a beginner in learning programming, more specifically JavaScript. I have come across a small problem while studying coding. When I use switch statements to solve a piece of problem, it produces right output.

```js
var dateNow = 3;
var dateSuffix;

switch (dateNow) {
  case 1:
  case 21:
  case 31:
    dateSuffix = "st";
    break;
  case 2:
  case 22:
    dateSuffix = "nd";
    break;
  case 3:
  case 23:
    dateSuffix = "rd";
    break;
  default:
    dateSuffix = "th";
    break;
}

console.log("Today is the " + dateNow + dateSuffix + " day.");
```

But when I do the same with if else statements, the output is wrong.

```js
var dateNow = 3;
var dateSuffix;

if (dateNow == 1 || 21 || 31) {
  dateSuffix = "st";
} else if (dateNow == 2 || 22) {
  dateSuffix = "nd";
} else if (dateNow == 3 || 23) {
  dateSuffix = "rd";
} else {
  dateSuffix = "th";
}

console.log("Today is " + dateNow + dateSuffix + " day of the month...");
```

Could anyone please point out the problem with my if statements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple conditions in if statement on both sides of the logical operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125750/multiple-conditions-in-if-statement-on-both-sides-of-the-logical-operator)

Comment: @Zenoo, thank you very much for the help. Your answer was very helpful, and I also learned a new technique from your answer.
Also, thanks to Lakmal Abesekara and KGSH bteam Mine Team Beast O_ for their support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `dateNow == 1 || 21 || 31`.

You need to use either `[1,21,31].includes(dateNow)`

Or `dateNow == 1 || dateNow == 21 || dateNow == 31`

```js
var dateNow = 3;
var dateSuffix;

if ([1,21,31].includes(dateNow)) {
  dateSuffix = "st";
} else if ([2,22].includes(dateNow)) {
  dateSuffix = "nd";
} else if ([3,23].includes(dateNow)) {
  dateSuffix = "rd";
} else {
  dateSuffix = "th";
}

console.log("Today is " + dateNow + dateSuffix + " day of the month...");
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var dateNow = 3;
var dateSuffix;

if (dateNow == 1 || dateNow ==21 || dateNow ==31) {
  dateSuffix = "st";
} else if (dateNow == 2 || dateNow ==22) {
  dateSuffix = "nd";
} else if (dateNow == 3 || dateNow ==23) {
  dateSuffix = "rd";
} else {
  dateSuffix = "th";
}

console.log("Today is " + dateNow + dateSuffix + " day of the month...");
```

I replaced your code

```
if (dateNow == 1 || 21 || 31) {
```

with is code `if (dateNow == 1 || dateNow ==21 || dateNow ==31) {` your code only trigger first if condition 
This code will help you

Comment: No explanation at all?

Comment: @Xufox i add  sir.

Comment: What do you mean by “your code only trigger first if condition”? It certainly does, but the explanation is incomplete as to why this happens. Or do you mean the first operand in the `||` chain? That would be incorrect.

Comment: @Xufox ok i understand.

Answer (score -1):

Update: As @Xufox pointed out, this answer is not true. This is false.

In addition to @Zenoo's answer, I have tested with this code:

```
dateNow = 2

console.log(dateNow == 1)
console.log(dateNow == 1 || 2)

console.log(true == 0)
console.log(true == 1)
console.log(true == 2)
```

Results:

```
false
2
false
true
false
```

My explanation is that `dateNow == 1 || 2` is treated as `(dateNow == 1) || 2` which is false as we can see.

Comment: No, `dateNow == 1 || 2` is never `false`. It’s either `true` or `2`.

Comment: But the value 2 is treated as false as we can see in the last testing 'case'.

Comment: No, that’s totally wrong. `false == 2` isn’t `true`. `==` coerces booleans to numbers, so you’re comparing `1 === 2` in the end, which of course is false. `Boolean(x)` is `true` for every _non-zero and non-NaN number_ `x`.

Comment: Oh okay. This answer is trash then, sorry.